# Behavior of named pipes on Windows in Go vs Python and other languages

Tags: go, winapi, named-pipes

I'm trying to use the API of [Soundpad](https://www.leppsoft.com/soundpad/en/rc/), which is exposed via a named pipe.
In Python, calling the API is as simple as

```py
import win32file

handle = win32file.CreateFile(
    r'\\.\pipe\sp_remote_control',
    win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    None,
    win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    None
)

win32file.WriteFile(handle, str.encode("DoPlaySound(2)"))
```

The specifics of the API do not matter for this question. What I do want to know is the difference between above Python code and the following code in Go:

```golang
import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/Microsoft/go-winio"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := winio.DialPipe(`\\.\pipe\sp_remote_control`, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)

    _, err = writer.WriteString("DoPlaySound(2)")
}
```

The connection to the named pipe is established and 14 bytes are written successfully, but Soundpad does not seem to receive the message for some reason.
I already looked into differences of encoding, but Go encodes all strings in UTF-8, same as Python 3.
I've also tried using `writer.Write(([]byte)("DoPlaySound(2)"))` with the same result.

To me, these two examples look exactly the same so I hope someone here can point out a difference and maybe help me figure out why the Go version is not working.

Comment: `bufio` suggests that the writer is buffered. Is there a flush operation?

Comment: Wow, apparently you are right. Adding a single `writer.Flush()` after the `WriteString()` call solves the problem and Soundpad receives the message. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Should be just a matter of your last line

```
_, err = writer.WriteString("DoPlaySound(2)")
```

to be

```
if _, err = writer.WriteString("DoPlaySound(2)"); err==nil {
    err=writer.Flush()
}
```

Whatever needs to be written to the pipe is still in the bufio.Writer buffer and needs to be flushed